# Cloud Architecture Stack Opinions - EC2 versus Azure

Tags: php, .net, azure, amazon-ec2, cloud-hosting

I have read many blog and articles about the pros and cons of **Amazon EC2** versus **Microsoft Azure** (and *Google's App Engine*). However, I am trying to decide which would better suite my particular case.

I have a data set - which can be thought of as a standard table of the format:

```
[id]  [name]  [d0]  [d1]  [d2] .. [d63]
---------------------------------------
0     Name1   0.43 -0.22  0.11   -0.81
1     Name2   0.23  0.65  0.62    0.41
2     Name3  -0.13 -0.23  0.17    0.00
...
N     NameN   0.43 -0.23  0.12    0.01
```

I ultimately want to do something that (despite my final chosen stack) would equate to an `SQL SELECT` statement similar to:

```
SELECT name FROM [table] WHERE (d0*QueryParameter1) + (d1*QueryParameter1) +(d2*QueryParameter2) + ... + (dN*QueryParameterN) < 0.5
```

where `QueryParameter1,2,N` are parameters supplied at runtime, and change each time the query is run (so caching is out of the question).

**My main concern is with the speed of the query**, so I would like advice on which cloud stack option would provide the fastest query result possible.

I can do this a number of ways:

- (1) Use **SQL Azure**, just as the query lies above. I have tried this method, and the queries can be quite slow as expected since SQL only gives you a single instance. I can spin up multiple instances of SQL and shard the data, but that gets real expensive real quick.
- (2) Use **Azure Storage Tables**. Bloggers claim storage tables are faster in general, but would this still be the case for my query requirements?
- (3) Use **EC2** and spin up several instances with *MySQL*, possibly incorporating sharding to new instances (cost increases though).
- (4) Use **EC2** with *MongoDB*, as I've read it is faster than `MySQL`. Again this is probably dependent on the type of query.
- (5) **Google AppEngine.** I'm not really sure how GAE would work with this query structure, but I guess that's why I am looking for opinions.

I'd like to find the best stack combination to optimize my specific need (outlined by the pseudo `SQL` query above).

Does anyone have any experience in this? **Which stack option would result in the fastest query containing many math operators in the `WHERE` clause?**

Cheers,
Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type of query with dynamic coefficients (weights) will require the entire table to be scanned on every query.  A SQL database engine is not going to help you here, because there is really nothing that the query optimizer can do.

In other words, what you need is NOT a SQL database, but really a "NoSQL" database which really optimizes table/row access to the fastest speed possible.  So you really shouldn't have to try SQL Azure and MySQL to find out this part of the answer.

Also, each row in your type of query is completely independent from each other, so it lends itself to simple parallelism.  Your choice of platform should be whichever gives you:

1. Table/row scan at the fastest speed
2. Ability to highly parallelize your operation

Each platform you mentioned gives you ability to store huge amounts of blob or table-like data for very fast scan retrieval (e.g. table storage in Azure).  Each also gives you the ability to "spin up" multiple instances to process them in parallel.  It really depends on which programming environment you're most comfortable in (e.g. Java in Google/Amazon, .NET in Azure).  In essence they all do the same thing.

My personal recommendation is Azure, since you can:

1. Store massive amounts of data in "table storage", optimized for fast scan retrieval, and partitioned (e.g. over d0 ranges) for optimal parallelism
2. Dynamically "spin up" as many compute instances as you like to process the data in parallel
3. Queueing mechanisms to synchronize the results collation

Azure does what you requires in a very "no-frills" way -- providing just enough infrastructure for you to do your job, and nothing more.

Comment: This is great info! And it cleared up a lot of my questions. Many thanks. I think I am leaning toward Azure tables for - as you said - the use of parallelism and my language of preference.

Comment: One followup question though: how is it possible to shard the data over several instances? For instance, how could we tell one InstanceA to only query the rows with PartitionKeyA, and InstanceB to only query rows with PartitionKeyB? (Sill learning the ins and outs of Azure).

Comment: @Brett, I haven't done much with partitioned Azure table data sets yet (not yet have so MUCH data), so you'll need to post another question on SO, I think.  My gut feel is the create a number of queues, one for each partition, then have one "feeder" instance read off the tables and the dump the jobs into different queues, with different back-end instances each feeding off a queue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the math operators or the number thereof, the problem is that they are parameterized - you are effectively doing a weighted average across the columns with the weights being defined at run-time, so that the operation must be computed and cannot be inferred.

Even in SQL Server, this operation can be parallelized (and this should show up on the execution plan), but it is not amenable to search optimization using indexes, which is where most relational databases will really shine.  With static weights and indexed computed column would obviously perform very quickly.

Because this problem is easily parallelized, you might want to look at something based on a [Map-Reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) principle.

Answer (score 0):

Currently neither SQL Azure nor Amazon RDS can scale horizontally (EC2 can at least vertically) but IF and only IF your data can be partitioned in a way that still makes it possible to execute your query the upcoming SQL Federations Feature of SQL Azure might be worth looking at and help making an informed decision.

MongoDB (which I like a lot) is more geared toward Document oriented workloads and is possible not the best solution for this type of job although your mileage may vary (it's blazingly fast as long as most of your working set fits into memory).

Comment: I don't think Mongo would help that much - Mongo's mainly blazingly fast because it allows quick writes and because it creates indicies for reads - but this data set won't have any writes and the indicies will not be very useful for these particularly queries (because the parameters change each time).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the QueryParameter0, QueryParameter1, ... , QueryParameterN are all supplied at runtime and are different each time, then I don't think that any of the platforms will be able to provide significant advantages over any of the others - since none of them will be able to take advantage of any pre-computed indicies.

With indicies removed, the only other factors for speed then comes from the processing power available - you already know about this for the SQL Azure option, and for the other options this pretty much comes down to you deciding what processing to apply - it's up to you to fetch all the data and to then process it.

One option you might consider is whether you could host this data yourself on an instance (e.g. using an Azure blob or cloud drive) and could then process the data in a custom built worker role. This isn't something I'd think about for general data storage, but if its just this one table and this one query then it would be pretty easy to hand craft a quick solution?

---

Update - just seen the answer from @Cade too - +1 for his suggestion of parallelization.